# Rationale for throwing static type?

Tags: c++, exception

According to [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.16), when one throws an object, it's thrown using the *static* type of the expression.  Hence, if you have:

```
catch ( some_exception const &e ) {
  // ...
  throw e; // throws static type, possibly causing "slicing"; should just "throw;" instead
}
```

and `e` is *actually* a reference to some class derived from `some_exception`, the above `throw` will cause the object to be "sliced" silently.  Yes, I know the correct answer is simply to `throw;`, but the way things are seems like an unnecessary source of confusion and bugs.

What's the rationale for this? Why *wouldn't* you want it to throw by the *dynamic* type of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "argument" to `throw` is an expression and it is the type of the expression that determines the type of the exception object thrown. The type of the expression thrown doesn't necessarily have to be a polymorphic type so there may not be a way to determine if the expression actually refers to a base class subobject of a more derived type.

The simpler "type of the expression" rule also means that the implementation doesn't have to dynamically determine the size and type of the exception object at runtime which might require more complex and less efficient code to be generated for exception handling. If it had to do this it would represent the only place in a language where a copy constructor for a type unknown at the call point was required. This might add significantly to the cost of implementation.

Answer (score 9):

When you `throw` something, a temporary object is constructed from the operand of the `throw` and that temporary object is the object that is caught.

C++ doesn't have built-in support for copying things or creating objects based on the dynamic type of an expression, so the temporary object is of the static type of the operand.

Comment: But if you catch by reference, it would seem like it could simply rethrow the same object without doing any copy at all (just like "throw;" does).

Comment: Then `throw x;` behaves differently depending on what its operand is and whether it appears in a `catch` block. The benefit of having `throw x;` distinct from `throw;` is that the behavior of `throw x;` is always the same (a copy is made and that copy is what is caught), but you still have the ability to rethrow the current exception if you want to do so.  [I should probably note that in some circumstances the copy can be elided, but only if doing so doesn't change the behavior of the program aside from the calling of constructors and destructors.]

Comment: And that's bad because...? It seems "less astonishing" to the user. If I catch by value, then of course it has to throw by the static type; but if I catch by reference, I don't see why different is bad.

Comment: @Paul, you always have to throw by copy because the original object might be in a part of the stack that is being unwound in the throw. Since a reference might be to an object with the same problem, it makes sense to be consistent.

Comment: @Paul, C++ is astonishing. You just have to get used to it.

Comment: I tend to think that consistency is a good thing:  I have a hard enough time remembering all the inconsistencies and variations in behavior that C++ already has.

Comment: @Paul You have to copy, because what you're throwing could be a temporary object on the stack.  And you can't use the dynamic type because there's no way of knowing the size or how to copy if the object is something like a dereferenced pointer.  (In theory, it shouldn't be that hard to make it work.  But a definition of the dynamic type might not be available at the site of the throw, so the compiler wouldn't know how to copy it.)

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas "_And that's bad because...?_" It's bad because it's unnecessarily complex and inconsistent. Isn't C++ already unnecessarily complex and inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that we can have references to objects where the static type of the reference is copyable, but the dynamic type of the object is not.

```
struct foo {};

struct ncfoo : foo
{
private:
    ncfoo(ncfoo const&) {}
};

ncfoo g_ncfoo;

void fun()
{
    foo& ref = g_ncfoo;
    throw ref; // what should be thrown here?
}
```

If you say "in this case just throw the static type", then how are the exact rules - what does "in this case" mean? References we just caught are "re-thrown" without copying, everything else is copied? Hm...

But however you define the rule, it would still be confusing. Throwing by-reference would lead to different behavior, depending on where we got that reference from. Neh. C++ is already complicated and confusing enough :)